# Authentication error while installing boost with Conan

Tags: c++, boost, conan

I'm trying to install boost with the following conanfile.txt file:

```
[requires]
cryptopp/8.2.0@bincrafters/stable
boost/1.64.0@conan/stable
gtest/1.8.1@bincrafters/stable
log4cplus/2.0.4@bincrafters/stable
OpenSSL/1.1.1@conan/stable
zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable
bzip2/1.0.8@conan/stable
lz4/1.8.0@bincrafters/stable 
snappy/1.1.7@bincrafters/stable 
zstd/1.4.0@bincrafters/stable

[generators]
cmake

[options]
OpenSSL:shared=True
boost:without_atomic=True
boost:without_wave=True
boost:without_container=True
boost:without_exception=True
boost:without_graph=True
boost:without_iostreams=True
boost:without_locale=True
boost:without_program_options=True
boost:without_random=True
boost:without_regex=True
boost:without_serialization=True
boost:without_coroutine=True
boost:without_fiber=True
boost:without_context=True
boost:without_timer=True
boost:without_thread=True
boost:without_chrono=True
boost:without_date_time=True
boost:without_log=True
boost:without_math=True
boost:without_type_erasure=True
boost:without_graph_parallel=True
boost:without_test=True
boost:without_mpi=True
boost:without_context=True

[imports]
bin, *.dll -> ./lib # Copies all dll files from packages bin folder to my "lib" folder
lib, *.dylib* -> ./lib # Copies all dylib files from packages lib folder to my "lib" folder
lib, *.so* -> ./lib # Copies all dylib files from packages lib folder to my "lib" folder
```

But for some reason I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR: boost/1.64.0@conan/stable: Error in source() method, line 70
>       tools.get(url, sha256=sha256)
>       AuthenticationException: Forbidden!

What is strange for me is that it did work until yesterday...
I would very much appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like boost sources are not available at the moment. See issue: 
https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues/1007

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is the source at

```py
"https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/%s/source/%s" % (self.version, zip_name)
```

not being accessible. The source uri is specified in `~/.conan/data/boost/x.xx.x/conan/stable/export/conanfile.py`.

A work around:
Please change the uri to another accessible one in the python code. Make sure the sha checksum matches.